# How to exclude the ul of a menu using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using two different functions in jQuery. One is to slideUp and slideDown of ul on hover of li. And second one is to display block the ul whose li is selected based on some text search in all li. But the problem is these two functions are conflicting each other. Both are working fine. But the first one override. [here is example](http://dev.kcseocompany.com/dagmar-new/product/wing-banner/)

My first to slide Up and slide down the sidebar menu on hover of li is:

```
$( ".sidebarnav ul.sf-menu" ).find('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('> ul').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('> ul').slideUp();
});
```

This is working fine The do what it is supposed to do.

My next code to auto selection and display the ul whose li is selected is:

```
var ptitle = $("p.productpage_title").text();

$('.sidebarnav .sf-menu ul li a').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() == ptitle; 
}).closest('ul').css({"display":"block"});
$('.sidebarnav .sf-menu ul li  a').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() == ptitle;
}).closest('ul').parent().closest('ul').css({"display":"block"});
```

The opens up the ul at first time when page is loaded. But when we hover on the ul on sidebar the first function work and then the second function does not open the ul.

I think this can be done by excluding the selected li from being slideUp on hover.

I used the .not() function but did not working for me.

Can any one please help me, How can I exclude the selected li by second function form  being slideUp on hover.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I want to use display block not the show and hide function. Because of some css issues.

Comment: Are you running the second block of code in an event handler?

Comment: no It is only in document ready function.

Comment: Then it only runs when the document is loaded. If you want it to run at other times, you need to put it in an event handler.

Comment: I also thought that n I did a little bit for this. I put second function after slideUp() in hover event but did not work, Any Guess why?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover will not fire unless you move the mouse across the element's boundary. Try explicitly calling `slideDown` in your 'second function' so that your 'selected' menu item is displayed as you expect.

```
$('.sidebarnav .sf-menu ul li a').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() == ptitle; 
}).closest('ul').css({"display":"block"}).slideDown();
```

Your general mechanism is a little clunky though. Consider making these adjustments to make it clearer.

- Add `data-title` attributes to your list item. This way you can select your elements directly without using the `filter` function.
- For that matter consider adding `data-title` attribute to each menu item
- Your long selectors (e.g. `.sidebarnav .sf-menu ul li a`) and use of `closest` are red flags to me.

Comment: Thankyou...This is working. I added this code after slideUp function.     And I will use data-title in my menu list item.